# Freeform error after major update

Tags: plugin-freeform

After updating from version 2.x to version 3.x with composer and terminal the plugin delivers this error:

> We’ve detected that both the new 3.x and old 2.x versions of Freeform
>   are installed.

But looking in the plugin settings and composer.json, there is only one plugin visible.

How can I get rid of this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out what caused the problem.

When changing from freeform 2.x to 3.x one has to change the wording in the composer.json from "solspace/craft3-freeform" to "solspace/craft-freeform" (delete the "3".

Comment: See https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/setup/updating-freeform-2.html#updating-from-2-x for further references.